# select_list should when the given value is not empty

Tags: ruby, watir

I have written the below code

```
b.select_list(:id,'something').select(a['value']) unless a['value].empty?
```

now I need to write the same code for many select select box, to avoid `unless a['value'].empty?`

I have included the function `selectIfnotempty?(item)` in class `SelectList`

```
def selectIfnotempty?(item)
    return item.empty?
    select item
end

def select(item)        
      matching_options = []
      perform_action do
        matching_options =
...
...
...
end
```

but it throws the error by saying

```
"undefined method `selectIfnotempty' for #<Watir::SelectList:0x132d2438>"
```

Can anyone clarify me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the method as `selectIfnotempty?` but calling it as `selectIfnotempty` (the question mark is missing).

The method itself will always return a boolean value (the result of `item.empty?`). I think you meant to return early *only* if `item` is empty.

```ruby
def selectIfnotempty?(item)
    return if item.empty?
    select item
end
```

Nitpick: In ruby the convention is to use `snake_case` for method names.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I called the method using wrong name and I haven't noticed that that method itself will always return a Boolean value, Thanks.